# SharePoint SPFx Graph API calls not working on Desktop Teams tab

Tags: spfx, microsoft-teams, graph-api, ms-graph-client

SharePoint SPFx Graph API calls not working on the Desktop Teams tab, It displays nothing on the Teams Tab. The same Teams Tab is working fine on the web browser. In the Teams tab, I just want to make a call to the Graph API calls to get the Mail messages and/or just read the User Profile from SharePoint.

I know this is a repeated question but I didn't get my solution on any of the existing blogs. I followed the different blocks, I followed [this block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860729/spfx-webpart-in-msteams-desktop-client-throws-an-unauthorizedaccessexception) but I didn't get success. I tried to debug the application, in the Desktop Teams Tab, I got the Access Denied error. The following is the URL generated and I got the Access Denied error.

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource=%27https://graph.microsoft.com%27&clientId='<Client Id of default Sharepoint app>'
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must access the SPO portal at least once with that account (I checked because the same thing happened to me).

Ref: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6136

Anoter option (I have not checked):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860729/spfx-webpart-in-msteams-desktop-client-throws-an-unauthorizedaccessexception